# Randomly generating a color for a certain object code in Python

Tags: python, colors

Hello I need some help with this: whenever I identify a certain object within the code that the color coincides with that object?
 An example of the code is presented below:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>**JACKS RUN RD CABLE #1___364**_</name>
    <description><![CDATA[<br><br><br>
<table border="1" padding="0">
<tr><td>Cable_Id</td><td>364</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cable_Name</td><td>JACKS RUN RD CABLE #1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Segment_Id</td><td>364-1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Map_Id</td><td>3283-1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Book_Number</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Reference_Drawing</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Cable_Gauge</td><td>19</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cable_Sheathing</td><td>COMM CABLE</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sheath_Pairs</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cable_Pairs</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>Aerial</td><td>T</td></tr>
<tr><td>Underground</td><td>F</td></tr>
<tr><td>Work_Order</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Narrative</td><td>1/4" MESSENGER</td></tr>]]></description>
    <Style>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>**ff0000ff**</color>
            <width>1.5</width>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <LineString>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>
            -80.043832,40.50061,0 -80.04006200000001,40.500929,0 -80.040018,40.500907,0 -80.03644300000001,40.500508,0 -80.035985,40.500468,0 -80.03517100000001,40.50039,0 -80.03325599999999,40.500213,0 -80.032264,40.499884,0 
        </coordinates>
    </LineString>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
```

The identifier is in BOLD and the color is in bold too. I need the color to change with each different Cable_Name. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try first generating a random number and then use this number faith the command to set color. I'm not very familiar with Python but that's just a way I though you could do it.

Comment: "_An example of the code is below_". You seem to have forgotten to include your code. All I see here is a part of an XML document.

Comment: Its not at all clear what you expect or want to happen here ...

Comment: I couldn't put the full code due to the sheer size of it. I meant to state that the example is the coding I need to manipulate and generate a random color to replace the *ff0000ff** that is based on the name **Jacks Run Rd. Cable #1**. Sorry I am semi new to Python.